# MOSFET operational amplifier - Exam

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am new to stackexchange. I have an exam tomorrow and i have a question from a past paper that i don't know how to answer. I would really appreciate if someone could possibly help me. Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: I don't see any value in mentioning the "mosfet" here. OPAMP is OPAMP.

Comment: Check out how input impedance is calculated for different op-amp based topologies.

Comment: This is a community driven site. Each member is representing the community. If you have got some reply from one of the members, it doesn't mean you will get any other. And any other member can reply instead. Or not reply at all. Also there are no strict timelines for the reply and no urgency. You get your answer whenever someone is finding it convenient for them to answer if at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not specify whether the amplifier should be inverting or not. Personally I would troll the teacher and give both answers.

The question does not specify at what frequency the input impedance should be 30 kOhm, therefore I will pick DC.

The fact that the opamp you will use is MOSFET-based is irrelevant except for one single detail: FET-input opamps have close to infinite input impedance at DC.

Thus the answer is :

- the textbook inverting opamp with 25dB gain and an input resistance of 30k, so the other resistor should be 30k times 25dB (533k)
- and the textbook non-inverting opamp with 25dB gain and a 30k resistor between the input and ground, because he wants a 30k input impedance so you give the client what he wants.

;)

Comment: @HamzaZaved It is not recommended to accept an answer so quickly on these SE sites. Because you have awarded the first answer, there is little incentive for others to add additional answers to your question as the 'prize' is already claimed. I kindly suggest waiting 24 hours before accepting an answer; in the meantime you can upvote as many positive answers as you like before accepting.